# How do I make picture stay on Picturebox?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, picturebox, graphing

I am drawing a graph on a picturebox on Windows Mobile Smart Device Application. The graph works well, but it disappears immediately afterwards.

I used the line:

```
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(picture2_show));
```

and my drawing method:

```
private void picture2_show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics objGraphics = this.pictureBox2.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Pen redpen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        int picBoxWidth = pictureBox2.Size.Width;
        int picBoxHeight = pictureBox2.Size.Height;
        int halfWidth = pictureBox2.Size.Width / 2;
        int halfHeight = pictureBox2.Size.Height / 2;

        Graphics objGraphic = this.pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();

        objGraphic.DrawLine(redpen, 0, 0, 0, picBoxHeight);
        objGraphic.DrawLine(redpen, 0, picBoxHeight - 1, picBoxWidth, picBoxHeight - 1);
        //Rectangle first = new Rectangle(0, halfHeight, picBoxWidth, halfHeight);

        Pen bpen = new Pen(Color.LawnGreen, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            objGraphic.DrawLine(
                bpen, 
                pictureBox2.Size.Width * i / array.Length,
                pictureBox2.Size.Height - array[i],
                pictureBox2.Size.Width * (i + 1) / array.Length,
                pictureBox2.Size.Height - array[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The picturebox stays, but how do I make the graph not disappear??

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw your graph in the picturebox's `Paint` event, using `e.Graphics`.
To force it to redraw, call `pictureBox2.Invalidate()`.

Do not draw on `CreateGraphics()`, since it will be erased when the control is next painted.